# Why does my file path in HTML work on my Server but not if I open the HTML File directly?

Tags: html, css, windows, file, server

MY file structure looks like this:
My Main file is in the Folder "HTML-Project/index.html" in this Folder is my style.css and 2 other folders, one is pictures (HTML-Project/pictures) and the other folder is a category folder, so
HTML-Project/categories and in the category folder I have the folder "category A" so the path is
HTMl-Project/categories/catgoryA and in this folder I have my HTML file for the category A, so the file structure looks like this HTML-Project/categories/catgoryA/categoryA.html.

I have the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">` in my `head` section in the file of category A and if i use the "Live Server" Extension on Visual Studio Code, it gets recognized and the stylesheet is used, however if i now just open the HTML file directly with my Browser the stylesheet doesnt get recognized.

> Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried changing the path many times, this were the paths i tried:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="HTML-Project/style.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/">`
I expected that some of these work but if i changed it to something like this, the Live Server also didnt work anymore, so i think `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">` must be right but it seemingly isnt.

Comment: With all those pathes you tried for the css file, could you see any error (except 404) in your console?

Comment: no i didnt but to be honest, im relatively new to coding and im not perfectly familiar with the vs code editor

Comment: Check browser console, it may be related to CORS. Remember, when you open an HTML file directly from your system (e.g., by double-clicking on the file), the file is loaded in your web browser without the context of a server. and the browser treats the file's location as the base URL and resolves relative file paths accordingly.

Comment: https://simplewebserver.org/download.html helps to run a simple webserver on your system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here because I can not write a comment.

Have you actually tried this? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`. Because it is working.

`/style.css` is not working because it stands for `file:///C:/style.css`. If you remove the slashes, it will work.

`/styles.css` works on the web server because it stands for `http://127.0.0.1:port/style.css`.

Another solution: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`

The dot indicates the current folder.